# Manually repair corrupted des3 encrypted file

Tags: bash, encryption, cryptography, openssl, des

I messed up my encrypted file, and I'm looking for help getting it back.  I'll skip to what I did, and what the problem is, ignoring the details of why I did this stupid thing without any backups.  Ok, so I did the following:

0. Created some important text

```
contents="important sekrit stuff"
```

1. Encrypted the text using openssl and des3 using the password "rightpass" and saved to file1

```
openssl des3 -k "rightpass" -in <(echo "$contents") -out "file1"
```

2. Decrypted the contents of file1 using the wrong password "wrongpass"

```
contents="$(openssl des3 -d -k "wrongpass" -in "file1")"`
```

3. Appended a line of text to the gobbledegook output

4. Encrypted that text and saved to file1 using the wrong password "wrongpass"

```
openssl des3 -k "wrongpass" -in <(echo "$contents" | awk -v k="new stuff1" -v n="newstuff2" '$1 != k {print $0} END {printf "%s %s", k, n}') -out "file1"
```

5. Realized what I just did, and shouted some rude words at my computer

6. Decrypted the contents of file1 using the wrong password "wrongpass" and saved it as file2

```
openssl des3 -d -k "wrongpass" -in "file1" >> "file2"
```

7. Removed the line of text from the end of the gobbledegook in file2 using a text editor, and saved the result to file2

8. Attempted to decrypt the contents of file2 using "rightpass"

```
openssl des3 -d -k "rightpass" -in "file2"
```

9. Got the output "bad magic number"

```
bad magic number
```

### My questions:

1. Is there any chance the gobbledegook I saved in file2 contains the encrypted information that was originally in file1?
2. Is there any way to restore and decrypt the information that file1 used to contain?  I hypothesized that there is some kind of binary thing at the end of the file that I need to remove or add or something that I can't do with a text editor.

Please keep in mind that although I am familiar with programming in general, I have little experience with encryption.  Thank you for your help.

### Update

Using @sth's suggestion, I encrypted the contents of file2 using "wrongpass" then decrypted using "rightpass", and when I decrypted, I got the message

```
>> openssl des3 -k "wrongpass" -in "file2" -out "file3"
>> openssl des3 -d -k "rightpass" -in "file3" -out "file4" 
bad decrypt
140735139465660:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
```

And "file4" was more gobbledegook.

Comment: For those of you voting to close - I realize this isn't a perfect fit for SO.  Could anyone please suggest a better place to post this?

Comment: I'd suggest http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Three other exchanges that come to mind (for me): [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). Maybe even the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If you write a script to solve the problem, then you could even try [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (that may even bring it back on-topic here). The folks on the Crypto SE might not be happy with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

After step 7 you should have the same file as after step 2 (decrypted with *wrongpass*).

So you should try to encrypt again with *wrongpass*, then decrypt with *rightpass*.

Comment: Thank you for the help - I updated my question above.  Still no luck - could it be a problem with the way I'm removing the added line in my text editor?  Couldn't there be an issue with editing binary data with a text editor (I'm using nano in this case).

Comment: There might be differences if the file should end in a newline or not. Also the editor you used to append/remove the line might have messed up special characters in the file.

Comment: Ok, I tried removing the last line with awk instead of an editor, and used a perl recipe I found `perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' filename` to remove the trailing newline (other encrypted files I examined did not have a trailing newline).  After all that I still get a `bad decrypt` message :(